# How can you write a "for x in xs" with a where clause on one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know if I can write the second line below somehow with one line.  How I have it below is not working:

```
for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/'):
    keys = [content['Key'] for content in page.get('Contents') if content.get("Size") > 0]
```

I get the Contents from the page and add it to keys only if the Contents "Size" is > 0.  Possible to do that in one line so no second for loop to test size?

Comment: Might it be possible to use the filter function? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: You're overwriting the `keys` variable each time through the loop. So at the end it just contains the values from the last page. What is your intended result?

Comment: Note that `content.get("Size)"` will return `None` if there _is_ no `Size` attribute, and `None > 0` will throw an exception. If there's _always_ going to be a Size, you might as well use `content['Size']` instead of using `get()`.

Comment: And if there might not be a `Size`, use `content.get("Size", 0)` to provide an appropriate default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple iterations in a list comprehension to combine the nested iterations into a flat result list.

```
keys = [content['Key'] for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/') 
            for content in page.get('Contents') if content.get("Size") > 0]
```